# C struct array input and output

Tags: arrays, c, struct, scanf, function-definition

I am trying to build a program which takes user input of employee details and prints it. I have separate functions for both of them.

Structure is as follows:

```
struct employee
{
    int empId;
    char name[20];
    char empType[10];
    int dd, mm, yyyy;
};

struct employee input()
{
    struct employee e;

    printf("Enter Employee ID: \n");
    scanf("%d", &e.empId);

    printf("Enter Employee name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &e.name);

    printf("Enter employee type: \n");
    scanf("%s", &e.empType);

    printf("Enter joining date: \n");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &e.dd, &e.mm, &e.yyyy);
}

void display(struct employee emp[], int n)
{
    printf("Employee ID \t Name \t Employee Type \t Joining date\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         printf("%d %s %s %d/%d/%d", emp[i].empId, emp[i].name, emp[i].empType, emp[i].dd, emp[i].mm, emp[i].yyyy);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;

    struct employee emp[n];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n ;i++)
    {
         emp[i] = input();
    }

    display(emp, n);

    return 0;
}
```

I am able to take the input properly but while printing I am getting all values as 0.
Requesting help!

Thanks!

Comment: Your `input` function is not `return`ing anything

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which is a single block of code that we can copy&paste, so that we can test the program. This block of code should also include all `#include` directives.

Comment: Read your compiler warnings

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That `for` loop is unneccessary - you would end up printing the output 5 times, for some reason.
Also use `typedef struct`, it's convenient.
And don't type `&` when dealing with struct's `string` elements.
This code is a mess, by the way.

Comment: Which for loop is unnecessary? Typedefs can be convenient, but can also hide the fact that a type is a struct, so not always the best way. You can (and must) use `&` on struct elements when you're trying to get `scanf()` to read, say, an `ìnt`. Or for any other reason you deem necessary. Not sure why you'd oppose doing that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was mistaken about the "&" thing. You just don't have to do that when asking for a "string" within a struct; in case of an int you have to, yes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You forgot about the return statement in the function `input`

```
//...
return e;
```

Also the arguments of these calls of `scanf`

```
printf("Enter Employee name: \n");
scanf("%s", &e.name);

printf("Enter employee type: \n");
scanf("%s", &e.empType);
```

are incorrect. You need to write

```
printf("Enter Employee name: \n");
scanf("%19s", e.name);

printf("Enter employee type: \n");
scanf("%9s", e.empType);
```

In general you should check that inputs were successful.

Comment: Having restricted the input to prevent buffer overflow, it is even more necessary to check that the following integer values are correctly scanned. Always check the function return value (items successfully scanned).